# How to prevent a field to be with a link

Tags: symfony, sonata-admin

I have an admin classe to store menu. Here she is

```
final class MenuAdmin extends AbstractAdmin
{
    protected function configureFormFields(FormMapper $formMapper)
    {
        $formMapper->add('id_menu', TextType::class);
        $formMapper->add('label', TextType::class);
        $formMapper->add('poids', IntegerType::class);
    }

    protected function configureDatagridFilters(DatagridMapper $datagridMapper)
    {
        $datagridMapper->add('id_menu');
        $datagridMapper->add('label');
        $datagridMapper->add('poids');
    }

    protected function configureListFields(ListMapper $listMapper)
    {
        $listMapper->addIdentifier('id_menu');
        $listMapper->addIdentifier('label');
        $listMapper->addIdentifier('poids');
    }
}
```

By default the fields are all coming with a link bringing on the edit page.

I would like to be able to say a field to be just a text fields without the link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We need to use : `->add` instead of `->addIdentifier`